# Update cart item quantity with ajax only works first time around

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When a clicks 'Add to cart', 1 item is added to the cart. Each item in the cart has a plus and minus sign so the user can increase by 1 or decrease by 1. If you click on the plus sign it should add one to the particular item clicked on. Currently this only works the first time clicked and not for the clicks thereafter. I am not sure if the issue is with the jquery or with the php.

```
$("body").on("click", ".cartPlus", function () {
        var itemToEdit = $(this).data('id');
        var qty = $(this).data('qty');
        var newQty = qty + 1;

        $.ajax({
                url: 'functions/show-cart.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    itemToEdit: itemToEdit,
                    newQty: newQty
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".price-xs").empty();
                },
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data.cart, function (index, item) {
                    console.log(item.each_item);

                });
            })

        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
        });

    });


if(isset($_POST['itemToEdit']) && $_POST['itemToEdit'] != "") {

    $i = 0;
    $item_to_edit = $_POST['itemToEdit'];
    $quantity = $_POST['newQty'];

        foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            while(list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {

                if($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_edit) {
                    array_splice($_SESSION['cart_array'], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_edit, "quantity" => $quantity)));

            }
        }
    }
}



if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {

    $itemsInCart = 0;
    $response['total'] = 0;
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {

        $featured = "Yes";
        $i=0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];

            $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `product_name`, `price`, `pic_name` FROM `products` as `p` INNER JOIN `product_images` as `pi` ON p.`id` = pi.`product_id` WHERE p.`id` = ? AND `featured` = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("is", $item_id, $featured);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $numRows = $result->num_rows;
            if($numRows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $product_name = sanitize($row['product_name']);
                    $price = sanitize(money_format('%.2n', $row['price']));
                    $subtotal = money_format('%.2n', $each_item['quantity'] * $price);
                    $pic_name = $row['pic_name'];
                    $cartTotal = $subtotal + $cartTotal;
                    $quantity = $each_item['quantity'];

                    $cart_details[] = array(

                    "product_name" => $product_name,
                    "price" => $price,
                    "subtotal" => $subtotal,
                    "pic_name" => $pic_name,
                    "each_item" => $quantity,
                    "item_id" =>$item_id,
                    "i" => $i

                    );

                    $i++;
                }
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }


    $response['total'] = $cartTotal;
    $response['cart'] = $cart_details;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: This is happening because you are not updating data('qty'), every time in the code it is giving you same value, Thus your quantity is always 1 more then the initial value.

Comment: Should that be updated just under my .done()  ?

Comment: yes you should update it just inside done method.

Comment: Hmm. excuse my ignorance but how do I update a data() value? I don't think I can use (this) `$(this).data('qty');`

Comment: Following is the example to update data parameter,                        var num = $('#foo').data("num") + 1;       
console.log(num)       
$('#foo').data('num', num); 
console.log(num)

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: please mark below answer as an answer and vote pls.

Comment: I can't mark as answer. I think you need to create a separate post, not just a comment on my question?

Comment: already added an answer, if this post is helpful then one up vote pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update data quantity like below example.

```
var num = $('#foo').data("num") + 1; 
console.log(num); 
$('#foo').data('num', num); 
console.log(num);
```